# Idea for a Zener Diode tester

Tags: arduino, zener, tester

I'm trying to distract myself right now, so I'm entertaining a light idea I've had in my head for a while.

I want to implement a Zener diode tester via Arduino that will measure Zeners going up to the supply could reach.

Here's how it'll work. The Arduino will measure the nominal forward voltage drop, taking note of the current consumption, by ways of how multimeters measure forward diode voltage drop, which seems accurate enough (dispute me on this). Multiply forward voltage drop & current consumed & you get the nominal wattage of the Zener at forward bias. Using some equation, this should output the nominal wattage of the Zener at reverse bias. That will be the limit of how we're gonna drive the zener at reverse bias. So, starting from an initial low current, measure & multiply the voltage to yield the wattage. As we step up the current, we are careful not to exceed the nominal wattage at reverse bias. Presto, the final voltage is the nominal voltage at reverse bias.

Issues:

- Does a multimeter really measure the nominal forward bias voltage for a current accurately enough?
- Equation to convert nominal forward bias wattage to nominal reverse bias wattage -- does it exist?
- Power supply separate from Arduino. Basically whatever you can plug the barrel connector. A wall wart with only a full bridge rectifier & capacitor is the standard power supply, I suppose.
- I've been looking at current source ICs & some are simply set by a single \$R_{set}\$. If the current sweep were to be done, then effectively a digital potentiometer is needed. Now, using a digital potentiometer programmed via SPI is not an option. Can you get away with a transistor for this?

Comment: Multimeters normally use a constand current source to measure the forward voltage drop a a diode. So please explain again how you want to use this information to get the power limit of a zener diode.

Comment: @kruemi Issue #1... Doing the current step up during reverse bias on the forward bias is repeating the same action. Ditch the forward bias measurement, then?

Comment: Ok... so "wattage" is a number in the datasheet. It's nothing you can measure easily. It depends on the materThe manufacturer defined wattage and the limits under which this applies. Trying to reduce a zener diode to one number is probably not very helpful anyway. Drop the idea and make a curve tracer instead :)

Comment: I think this can't work. Different Zener diodes have their nominal Zener voltage rated at some specifc test current. If you don't know what Zener it is, you don't know what the test current should be, so you also don't know wha current to use to measure the Zener voltage, and there is no way to detect how much power it can dissipate. For zener diodes with less than 5V reverse voltage, the "knee" is very soft so it will be hard to detect from the I-V curve what the Zener voltage is

Comment: You should be able to safely guess the wattage from the package - typically 250 mW, 500 mW, and 1 watt. Enter that as a limiting parameter. Start with a current pulse of 1 mA. This should be OK up to 250 volts. Calculate the power, and keep stepping up current until you reach the wattage limit. You should be able to deduce the knee of the curve by determining the best V/I point below maximum wattage. Using pulses will assure that the device does not heat up.

Comment: I don't understand how you will measure the nominal wattage. By the way there isn't a nominal wattage - only a maximum wattage. If you go past the maximum wattage the smoke might come out of the diode.

Comment: _”Does a multimeter really measure the nominal forward bias voltage for a current accurately enough?”_ No.

Comment: My approach has shifted to finding the knee of the I-V curve. The technique will involve using a modified Newton-Rhapson Method which probes in pulses. I know the technique hasn't been invented yet.

Comment: A curve tracer, eh? Seems to be a more versatile & robust rig. A bit of trouble to hook it up whenever I need to test a single Zener. I was thinking of a handheld device, albeit the power cord. Should I abandon this?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: It won't work

Longer answer

- Multimeters measure the forward voltage with pretty high precission. That does not mean that they show something that makes sense in all cases or even that different multimeters will show the same result. There are several reasons for this. One is, that there is not a defined current at which the voltage drop of a diode has to be measured. 1mA seems to be quite common but many Multimeters use 100uA (probably the same current source they use to measure resistors).
- No, there is no such formula. You won't get any wattage form any measurment. The maximum power dissapiation (wattage) is a number the manufacturer puts in the datasheet.
- Power Supply: whatever you need. Define, what the maximum voltage is you want to measure and what kind of circuitry you need to supply it and measure it.
- Look for a *current (sinking) DAC*. For example the Analog Devices [AD5821](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ad5821.html) or the Maxim [DS4412](https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/analog/data-converters/digital-to-analog-converters/DS4412.html)

What you CAN so with your idea (which is a nice and usefull project) is a curve tracer. A device in which you can insert different components that will output a V/I curve or table (bipolar ideally). This is a great help in identifying components or finding broken components.

Comment: AD5821 & DS4412? No, I'm not inclined to use I2C (slightly better, though), & there is the Arduino. I'd stick with those current sources set by an \$R_{set}\$. I know how to drive them now (hint: current mirror).

Comment: It is possible to estimate a diode's rated dissipation "wattage" by integrating the power dissipated on the diode, using the forward voltage change to determine the change in absolute temperate (per Shockley model, for example), approximating the junction-to-ambient thermal resistance and the diode's thermal mass, and figuring out in which "ballpark" of diode wattages it fits. It would be largely a gimmick, though, since the thermal mass and thermal impedance are not always commensurate with the ratings. E.g. a diode in a glass package same as 1N4148, might only have a 15mA absolute maximum.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Something like that might be an Idea for a research paper... It could work but only as long as thermals are the limiting factor and the bonding wires don't act as a fuse before that...